# How list<T> to check whether contains a custom struct?

Tags: c#, list

I have the following implementation

```
// Contains returns true if the specified element is in the List.
// It does a linear, O(n) search.  Equality is determined by calling
// item.Equals().
//
public bool Contains(T item) {
    if ((Object) item == null) {
        for(int i=0; i<_size; i++)
            if ((Object) _items[i] == null)
                return true;
        return false;
    }
    else {
        EqualityComparer<T> c = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
        for(int i=0; i<_size; i++) {
            if (c.Equals(_items[i], item)) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

If `item` is a `struct` value type, does the flow go into the `if` block, rather than the `else` block?
I am confused about this implementation.

Can anyone explain to me how the  `Contains` method can evaluate value types like a `struct` ?

Comment: It will go to the `else` block , where there - it  will search if Equals has been override using the more specific type rather than Equals(Object). I don't understand the  question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `if` part is only checking if we are looking for `null` item in the list. If we do, then it goes through the list and looks for `null` value in the items of the list. This part is only valid for reference types, because value types cannot be `null`.

The `else` part of the other hand is doing all the checking in cases when item is not `null`, so this code is used for `structs` as well. What it does is it gets a default equality comparer for the type (`EqualityComparer<T> c = EqualityComparer<T>.Default`) and uses this comparer to find the item in the list.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to understand is the difference between a `value type` and a `reference type`.

`struct`, just like an `int`, `long`, etc. is not stored on the `heap` but on the `stack`. A `reference type` has a pointer (which is a memory address) stored on the `stack` that points to the actual object data is stored on the `heap`.

(Go read up on the difference between a stack and a heap.)

However, adding a `struct` to something like a `ArrayList` or even `List<object>` will still work because it will most probably be boxed into a `reference type` first and thus a `struct` wil **not be** `null`, even if you passed a `default(<struct type>)` it will still **not be** `null`.

Then it will follow like @dotnetom has explained with the `else` part executing and evaluating wether a `struct` is in the collection or not.